# How to make newInstance from ctClass in javassist?

Tags: instance, javassist

I can make a instance:

```
Class<?> jClazz = Class.forName(XXXX);
jClazz.newInstance();
```

but I need modify the class by javassist:

```
CtClass ctClass = cp.get(path);
CtConstructor m = CtNewConstructor.make("public " + className + "() {}", ctClass);
ctClass.addConstructor(m);
```

Now,I want to make a instance from ctClass.How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize CtClass by using ClassPool. Here is an example

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
Class<?> clazz = pool.toClass(ctClass);
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
System.out.println("Instance: " + instance);
```